# LayoutAnimationController in order to display one by one element of list

Tags: android, android-animation

So I'm facing this problem:
I need to display a list of item loaded asynchronously.
When they are loaded, I want to display them one by one. I try to use the LayoutAnimationController. But it seems that it has issues and i can't understand what it is.

Here is my code :

```
    this.adapter = new ReactionTypeAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_reaction_type, reactionTypeArrayList); // reactionTypeArrayList at this stage.
    reactionTypeListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f); // these are de debug parameters in order to see if the animation play
    animation.setDuration(500);
    final LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(animation, 0.5f);
    controller.setOrder(LayoutAnimationController.ORDER_NORMAL);
    reactionTypeListView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);

    reactionTypeRepository.retrieveAll(new IRepositoryCallback<ArrayList<ReactionType>>() {
        @Override
        public void OnSuccess(ArrayList<ReactionType> entity) {
            adapter.addAll(entity);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void OnError() {

        }
    });
```

I tried to set the adapter inside the OnSuccess callback, but the result is the same.

And strangely, when using the instant run from Android Studio, I have the expected result. But when refreshing the whole app, i see no animations

Answer (score 0):

Here is lib that gives you perfect result :

https://github.com/Jaouan/ViewsFrom

Comment: This does not fill my requirements. I'd like to understand what was the problem with this piece of code. Thank you anyway for trying to help me ;)